# N210 not recognized under gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, software-defined-radio, uhd

I have an ETTUS Research [N210](https://www.ettus.com/product/details/UN210-KIT) software defined radio (SDR) connected to my laptop. The device is recognized under macos and also under an Ubuntu on top of a virtual box. These commands:

```
uhd_usrp_probe --args=addr=192.168.10.2
```

and

```
uhd_find_devices --args=addr=192.168.10.2
```

and even

```
rx_ascii_art_dft --args=addr=192.168.10.2 --freq 92000000 --gain 30 --rate 8000000 --frame-rate 15 --ref-lvl -50 --dyn-rng 70
```

work perfectly and deliver results. But whenever I start the `gnuradio-companion` with a simple flow graph, I get the following error (BOTH directly under macos and on top of VirtualBox Ubuntu):

```
[ERROR] [UHD] Device discovery error: unknown key format 192.168.10.2
Runtime

RuntimeError: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Device Address: 192.168.10.2
```

In the flow graph, I put the device address in the properties window of "USRP Source--> General --> Device Address".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution in one [of the replies in ETTUS forum](http://ettus.80997.x6.nabble.com/USRP-users-GNU-Radio-USRP-Image-Issues-tp5227p5234.html). So I put it here in the hope it can be useful for others facing the same problem. The device address field of the USRP source in `gnuradio-companion` should not be filled with just "192.168.10.2" but with "addr=192.168.10.2". This solved the problem for me. [image]